# Wordpress function to target 1, 2-3, 4-5 posts to apply different code/style

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to target the first post, second-third post and fourth-fifth post to achieve a tiled like image effect in Bootstrap and Wordpress. I made a plugin to handle this code and make it a shortcode as well but I get an error on it. I know it could be shortened due to my php knowledge is at beginner level. Any help in shortening it would be appreciated or at least solve the error issue I am having if at all possible. I have the CSS working great but not the php code. [I am trying to achieve this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fSGmuC0Y2yVyzcz9Ckr_zsS3_RHgrv6r/view?usp=sharing).

[I started with this code](https://gist.github.com/justawebbie/89054b7a4b18afc58df6d48500c71156)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can make it simple by add a variable and increase it on loop and check on every time 
it will make you control on every post

```
$i=0;
```

before

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```

then check if it first post like

```
if($i==0) : echo 'class="active"'
```

then increase it in every loop

```
$i++; endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: I have seen that but I need more than just a class added to each post. I am making it in bootstrap so there are columns and rows which need to be added depending on where the image will go. So how would I do that?

Comment: you can more than add class with this code it is example for like where the post thumbnail will view and title only remove echo and class and add the code you want @dreamweaver

Comment: Okay, and would i do an `if($i==2) : then do something` and so forth. I am really new to this and trying to understand. thank you for your help.

Comment: excellent  , go forward and mark this answer as useful for other @dreamweaver

Comment: Okay I started this and would like you to look it over and tell me what I have done wrong please.

Comment: I could not get it to let me format this sorry.......`<div class="container dynamicTile">
 <div class="row tile-row">
  <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 tile-col">
<?php $i=0; ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php if($i==0) : echo '<div class="tile-wrapper tile-img">' ?>
     <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large', array( 'class'=> 'img-fluid img-repsonsive')); ?>
     <?php echo '<div class="title-box">' ?>
           <?php the_title(); ?>`

Comment: Here is the full code in a good format to look over. 'https://gist.github.com/justawebbie/056b8a21f56a64123a1cc00bfcb11cf7'